# Using plugins on phone gap (cordova) 3.4

Tags: file, cordova, plugins, inclusion

I'm currently developing a Phonegap project which use https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/617 plugin but i don't know how to integrate it and the doc is... kind of empty about it. I'm running on mac,
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, not sure what is up with the new documentation (can't find anything). What I have been doing is: go to http://docs.phonegap.com > change the version (top right) to 3.3.0 and then find the API you are looking for.

Here is link to the one above (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File)

Comment: Thanks, but no its not working because the xml is different on 3.4 :/

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything with xml. Are you using PhoneGap Build or building locally?

Comment: did you run `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file` and then `cordova build`? That should install the plugin without needing to edit any xml.

Comment: sure i did `phonegap plugin add org.apache.cordova.file` and then i build it but... nothing append i used the example js code but it doesn't seems to respond